# Autocomplete issue in Yii

Tags: yii, autocomplete, invoice

I'm using [this](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)
auto-complete plugin with my new project. It's working fine. See [image](http://picturepush.com/public/13428420)

But I want to populate these fields when I select the result.

Here is my code:

```
 var as = $("#query" + x + "").autocomplete({
        minChars: 1,
        maxHeight: 100,
        serviceUrl: 'index.php?r=purchaseorder/list',

    });
```

IN CONTROLLER

```
    public function actionList() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = array('id','description','unit','rate');
    $criteria->addSearchCondition("description", $_GET['query']);
    $criteria->limit = $this->limit;


    $items = Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $suggestions = array();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($items as $c) {
        $suggestions[] = $c->description;
        $data[] = $c->id;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    echo CJSON::encode(
            array(
                'query' => 'q',
                'suggestions' => $suggestions,
                'data' => $data
            )
    );
    exit;
}
```

grid jquery

```
  jQuery("#addrow").click(function() {

        jQuery(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row">\n\
<td>\n\
<span id="delete' + x + '" style="cursor: pointer" class="icon-remove"></span>\n\
</td>\n\
<td class="item-code"><input autocomplete="off" name="code[]" id="code' + x + '" type="text" class="input-code"/></td>\n\
<td class="item-description"><input autocomplete="off" name="q" id="query' + x + '" type="text" class="input-description"/></td>\n\
<td class="item-unit"><input readonly autocomplete="off" name="unit[]" id="unit' + x + '" type="text" class="input-unit"/></td>\n\
<td class="item-qty"><input name="qty[]" autocomplete="off" value="0" id="qty' + x + '" type="text" class="input-qty"/></td>\n\
<td class="item-rate"><input readonly name="rate[]" autocomplete="off" value="125.25" id="rate' + x + '" type="text" class="input-rate"/></td>\n\
<td class="item-discount"><input name="discount[]" autocomplete="off" value="0.00" id="discount' + x + '" type="text" class="input-discount"/></td>\n\
<td class="item-total"><input name="total[]" readonly autocomplete="off" value="0.00" id="total' + x + '" type="text" class="input-amount"/></td>\n\
</tr>');
```

controller is already there

Comment: what problem are you getting ?? Is auto complete not getting data ??

Comment: When u select sony its code and unit should be populated ??

Comment: no its working fine...but i dont know how to populate those fields...see image

Comment: yes thats what i wanna do... :)

Comment: U have posted the code for auto complete which works fine post the code which displays the grid view and controller for it

Comment: grid is done by jquery...

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g600f15bb99dd540a999318482e0bb0c8000d75918                 i upload the files

Comment: i can give you a hint . On select of autocomplete options make an ajax call and retrive data of the selected item and populate it in the fields using javascript

Comment: can u please give me a sample code of that...big help friend

Comment: Ok wait i will try to provide u sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it like this...
**IN JQUERY....**

```
var as = $("#query").autocomplete({
        minChars: 1,
        maxHeight: 100,
        serviceUrl: 'index.php?r=purchaseorder/list',
        onSelect: function(suggestion) { 
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            row.find('.input-code').val(suggestion.id).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            row.find('.input-description').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            row.find('.input-unit').val(suggestion.unit).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            row.find('.input-rate').val(suggestion.rate).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
            row.find('.input-qty').focus();
        }       
    });
```

AND THEN **IN CONTROLLER**

```
    public function actionList() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = array('description', 'id','unit','rate');
    $criteria->addSearchCondition("description", $_GET['query']);
    $criteria->limit = $this->limit;

    $items = Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $suggestions = array();
    $x=0;
    foreach ($items as $c) {
        $suggestions[$x]['value'] = $c->description;
        $suggestions[$x]['id'] = $c->id;
        $suggestions[$x]['rate'] = $c->rate;
        $suggestions[$x]['unit'] = $c->unit;
        $x++;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    echo CJSON::encode(
            array(
                'suggestions' => $suggestions,
            )
    );
    exit;
}
```

thats it...!

Answer (score 0):

Sample code as shown below

```
$('#yourautoCompleteId').change(function(){
    var selecteddata=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "'.$this->createUrl('Controller/yourMethod').'",
        data: {
            //special:specialisation,
            data   :selecteddata,
            },
            type:"GET",//you can also use POST method
            dataType:"html",//you can also specify for the result for json or xml
            success:function(response){
                //write the logic to get the response data as u need and set it to the fields 
                $("#dataId").val("SetHere");
                $('#quantityId').val("setHere");
             },
             error:function(){
                    //TODO: Display in the poll tr ifself on error   
                    alert("Failed request data from ajax page"); 
                }
        });
})
```

get the data in the controller using post and query with this data and send the result as u need and set to the fields as shown in the sample

Comment: i will try this and give u feed back

Comment: thanks to you,this method works fine....(for now its ok) but if I can get the job done by DIVBRIDGE method,thats really what I want...

Comment: make use of the property onselect property https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete provided by auto complete API

Comment: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g600f15bb99dd540a999318482e0bb0c8000d75918 THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE TRIED...PLEASE HELP ME BRO...

Comment: you have missed "value" attribute for your code and unit fields in .js file and given hardcode value to unit price field 125.25 .Instead you use ajax and get the required value and and set to the value attribute  of the fields thats it

Comment: i tried that,when i pass json array(contains:code,description,unit,rate) from controller to devbadge method,it doesnt even display suggestions,also i cant access that json array from that method.iam not good at jqeury(may be thats why).main thing i want is display description value on suggestion list and populate other values when i select one suggestion.if you can give me a sample code grate(i know you have lot of works :) but plzzzz)

Comment: Go through the code provided there u may get some clue http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/

Comment: Or else when u select the option from auto select u process and bring all the required data without using ajax and using select: property of autocomplete load the data as shown in the above thread

Comment: Thanks Ninad... I did it... :) tkz a lot